# Laravel route optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i have one issue with the Laravel routes.

I have one function `index($sport = '', $date = '');` this function shows me the news for a specific sport and date. But sometimes these parameters are not entered and I want to display all news. This works so fine so good, the problem is with the route.

This is the route code I have used:

```
Route::get('/news/{sport?}/{date?}.html', ['as' => 'news.index', 'uses' => 'NewsController@index']);
```

The problem comes when there is no sport and date entered, than the URL is domain.com/news.html, but is not caught with that code. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about `news` and `sport` as resources you could have something like that:

```
// index case news
Route::get('/news.html', ['as' => 'news.index', 'uses' => 'NewsController@index']); 

// show case news
Route::get('/news/{date}.html', ['as' => 'news.show', 'uses' => 'NewsController@show']); 

// index case sport
Route::get('/news/sport.html', ['as' => 'sport.index', 'uses' => 'SportController@index']); 

// show case sport
Route::get('/news/sport/{date}.html', ['as' => 'sport.show', 'uses' => 'SportController@show']);
```

A different approach would be:

```
 // index case news
Route::get('/news.html', ['as' => 'news.index', 'uses' => 'NewsController@index']); 

// sport case
Route::get('/news/{sport}.html' , ['as' => 'sport.index', 'uses' => 'SportController@index'])
     ->where(['sport' => '[0-9]+']);

// date case
Route::get('/news/{date}.html', ['as' => 'news.show', 'uses' => 'NewsController@show'])
     ->where(['date' => '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,}-[0-9]{1,}']);

// sport and date case
Route::get('/news/{sport}/{date}.html' , ['as' => 'sport.index', 'uses' => 'SportController@show'])
     ->where(['sport' => '[0-9]+', 'date' => '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,}-[0-9]{1,}']);
```

Comment: thankss @borracciaBlu. Your second approach helped me a lot to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

theres so many ways todo that, but for the simplest way, just add another route for displaying all list, `Route::get('/news/','NewsController@index');`

Comment: but for some reason it displays me now the first url like that: http://domain.com/news.html?date=2016-11-23&sport=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple , you should try this approach

```
domain.com/news.html?date=2016-11-23&sport=1
```

if date and sport not found in url you can show all result 
and it is easy readable syntax if some one want to bookmark this url.